# Why was question about web page usage migrated to SO?

Tags: discussion, migration

Just curious as to why the following question has just been migrated to Stack Overflow:
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/59688/tabbing-through-a-textarea-that-captures-tab

It doesn't appear to be programming related and is asking about general web page usage - from a users perspective. The linked jsfiddle is just an example of this behaviour.

Comment: it's not about use of any webapp.

Comment: @Sathya True, although neither is it about programming. Maybe SuperUser would have been more appropriate as it's possibly about the browser?

Answer (score 2):

The question wasn't about usage of a webapp. Should it have been migrated to Super User? I'd think not. (Note: I'm a Super User Moderator too.)

This line from OP:

> How can I get out these textareas using keyboard so I can continue switching fields?

Made me assume he's working on a webpage he's working on webpage and needs suitable method to implement this & that's why I migrated it to Stack Overflow

Comment: The way I read it that's a question about sites possibly breaking web browser functionality. I'd think it would be more appropriate at [su].